# Converting Form Data to XML

Tags: php, xml, ajax, forms, contacts

I'm using PHP in my contact form to send an email to but I need the output to be emailed in XML format. How do I convert the form data to XML? I tried looking around for this but the only helpful information I could find was for ASP. Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific? what fields do you have on your form and how do you want the XML to look like?

Comment: Actually needs to be sent in ADF (auto-lead data format) but it's an XML based standard designed by the auto industry. I'll only be using text fields and there will be one for name, email, phone, vehicle, and time

Comment: Did you still have problem with this? Or did you find a solution with one of those answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ie.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php - should have you up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php), works great in my RSS parsers.

For a more detailed help, you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just needed to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to send it as XML? and how does it need to be sent?

you can loop through your post variables and create xml items for each post variable.

Comment: It needs to be sent as XML because the CRM that is being used won't identify the email as a lead unless it is formatted this way. I'm a noob but I think I'm headed in the right direction. Thanks!