# Saving HTML input data to XML

Tags: html, xml, input, save

I've searched through the forum and couldn't find a specific answer on my troubles.

What I want to do, is having a simple form, where a user can input information and then, when a button is pressed, get it saved on the server. And if its possible get the XML document saved with the name that specified in the first field.

I need to pull out the information in an app written in action script. Which is, sad to say, the only language I know properly.

I'm trying to get my information from this form (it should be bigger, but right now, I just need a working example):

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<br>    
Activity: <input type="text" id="activity1" name="activity1">
<br>
Activity: <input type="text" id="activity2" name="activity2">

<input type="submit" id="btnSub" name="btnSub" value="Save">
</form>
```

To be saved in a XML document.

And as said, everything is going to be on the server. If it helps anything.
I can't use ASP as one.com doesn't support this. :/

Hopefully some of you are able and willing to help me out.

I'll try to answer everything thats unclear.

Comment: What scripting languages DOES one.com support? You cannot do this with any server-side script.

Comment: HTML, Javascript, PHP, JQuery and so on. Can't it be executed in HTML5 in some way, that it should write to an XML file? MySQL is another solution but then i need to ask for help for that too. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097810/converting-form-data-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help:

http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_431-xml-to-string-and-string-to-xml-in-javascript

You can then use an AJAX call in jQuery to send the data to PHP to save it if that is what you are needing.

EDIT: However, I do feel that it is much easier for this to be done server-side. I'm not great with PHP but it's very simple in .NET (unfortunately you explained you can't use this option).